# Reference variables in C++

Tags: c++, c, reference

Why are reference variables not present/used in C?

Why are they designed for C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C was invented first. I don't know if they hadn't thought about references at the time (being mostly unnecessary), or if there was some particular reason not to include them (perhaps compiler complexity). They're certainly much more useful for object-oriented and generic constructs than the procedural style of C.

Answer (score 5):

Reference arguments were originally invented, AFAIK, for one thing: **operator overloading semantics**. For example, operator[] just must return a reference.

It was then a subject of great debate whether the 'concealed pointer' should be used for anything else ever.

Many development convention documents of many firms said "never use references. If you need a pointer, say so".

However, it was then discovered that references have one major advantage (no, not the syntax sugar). It is this: a reference is guaranteed to be valid, unless you work really hard to break it.

Personally, I still don't understand why I cannot do this in C++:

```
int a1, a2;
int &b = a1;
&b = a2; // Error. address of referenced is not an lvalue. Why?!
```

Comment: That code makes no sense. The second line tries to initialise an integer from a pointer; the third tries to assign an integer to a temporary pointer. Both of these give a type mismatch. The error tells you that you can't assign to a temporary; even if you could, then it would have no effect since the temporary is immediately destroyed. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: The third line tries to assign the address of `b`, which is (in a sense) the same as trying to relocate the variable `b` to the specified address.  I can't think of a case where you would want to do this.  If you need a variable associated with a particular memory location, use a `void*` to point to a memory address.  Allowing something like this would also mean that `&b = &a2` would be allowed, which would result in both (unique) variables `b` and `a2` at the same address, which makes no sense.  Arbitrarily "moving" a variable like that will mess up memory offsets generated by the compiler.

Comment: sorry me idiot. fixed code. please disregard whatever you think I meant.

Comment: @Pavel:  Aside from the fact that you can't reseat references in C++ (which is what you're talking about), you've still got a syntactic problem, since `&b` already has a meaning.

Comment: Operator[] can easily return a pointer.  I believe it was more the parameters to operator+, for instance, that made references neccessary.

Comment: @David: &b has a meaning, which is the address pointed by the reference == the address of b. They just didn't think about this syntax as a cute way to reset the reference.

Answer (score 1):

They're not present in C because they're not required.  C has very few 'extraneous' features.  You can write any program without using references, so they're just not included.  C++ was developed much later than C was, so its designers threw in all kinds of stuff that wasn't originally present in C.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, C predates C++ by approximately a decade.  References were a feature introduced in the C++ language.  Some features of the C++ language have been adopted by subsequent versions of the C standard (such as const and // comment).  The concept of references has not been so far.

One can hypothesize that their usefulness in object oriented programming does not translate as usefully to the procedural programming of C.

Answer (score 1):

I think I agree with Pavel's idea that they were invented to make overloaded operators work properly. It's pretty clear that the first versions of C++ (C with classes) did not have references as if they did, `this` would be a reference instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess C was born with a minimalist hat, and references are just syntactic sugar for pointers.

Comment: That's a very simplistic view of references and though technically (at a very low level) true not actually an accurate description of what references are.